# virtualenv ошибка на сервере

Tags: python, linux, virtualenv

Приветствую!

Друзья, возникла проблема при работе с virtualenv для python 3.5.2

При запуске команды: "virtualenv --python=python3.5 env" появляется следующая лабуда:

```
$ virtualenv --python=python3.5 env
Already using interpreter /usr/local/bin/python3.5
Using base prefix '/usr/local'
New python executable in /var/www/*********/www/env/bin/python3.5
Also creating executable in /var/www/*********/www/env/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
  Complete output from command /var/www/...ww/env/bin/python3.5 - setuptools pip wheel:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 7, in 
  File "", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/__init__.py", line 16, in 
  File "", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/vcs/subversion.py", line 9, in 
  File "", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/index.py", line 30, in 
  File "", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/wheel.py", line 6, in 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/compileall.py", line 20, in 
    from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/__init__.py", line 17, in 
    from concurrent.futures.process import ProcessPoolExecutor
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 55, in 
    from multiprocessing.connection import wait
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 23, in 
    from . import reduction
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 135, in 
    import array
  File "", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "", line 954, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "", line 896, in _find_spec
  File "", line 1139, in find_spec
  File "", line 1113, in _get_spec
  File "", line 1225, in find_spec
  File "", line 1264, in _fill_cache
OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory: '/var/www/*********/www/env/lib/python3.5/plat-linux'
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in 
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 711, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 944, in create_environment
    download=download,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 900, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 795, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /var/www/...ww/env/bin/python3.5 - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1
```

Проблем с памятью быть не должно, ибо:

```
$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1024        157        866        140          0        142
-/+ buffers/cache:         14       1009
Swap:         1024          0       1024
```

И на диске с местом все хорошо

```
$ df
Файловая система 1K-блоков Использовано Доступно Использовано% Cмонтировано в
/dev/simfs        10485760      4521156  5964604           44% /
devtmpfs            524288            0   524288            0% /dev
tmpfs               524288            4   524284            1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               524288         7756   516532            2% /run
tmpfs                 5120            0     5120            0% /run/lock
tmpfs               524288            0   524288            0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs               524288        25688   498600            5% /tmp
none                524288            0   524288            0% /run/shm
```

Не сталкивались ли Вы ранее с таким? Можете что-нибудь посоветовать?

Comment: попробуйте переустановить системный питон.

Answer (score 0):

virtualenv -p python3.5 namevenv